# value wont change in an event

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I've create a list of canvases in wpf, and I have a button click event. I want that when I press the button it will add to the list new canvas. but when I try to change the property of the canvas in another window, it says the index was out of bounds, which means the list didnt add the canvas. I've created a method to check that and indeed it says the index is 0.
I've this with an array also, same here, I change its value but its still wrote the value is 0. this is the code:

```
public partial class New_Paint : Window
{
    public List<Canvas> paintsList = new List<Canvas>();
    public Canvas painting = new Canvas();

    private void ok_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        paintsList.Add(painting);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is the moethod to check its size:

```
public int getSize()
{
    return paintsList.Count;
}
```

and here is the code in the main window:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = paint.getSize() + "";
}
```

the methos return 0 although i click "ok". the list just wont add the items.

Comment: yes i just didnt wrote it here

Comment: yes everything is working except what i mentioned above

Comment: this.Close I assume closes the Window, right?

Comment: And where are you adding to "paint?" Because you are doing paint.getSize and not adding anything to it.

Comment: at first i was adding to it, but every time it crushed, so i wanted to see if it adds items to the list, hence the getSize method

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're new at this?  Your list of  canvases belong to your instance of New_Paint,  and you only add one canvas to that list before closing the window (at least in the code you've shown). I  don't see why you would expect more than one.  You need to have a  master list  of canvases that is owned by whatever is managing your child windows.

Comment: yes im new at this.
but whenever i call the New_Paint i create a new canvas, so whats the problem? its not only just one, and even if it does, its anyway not on the list

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense, though. You probably want a click handler on the OK button rather than a MouseUp handler. Are you changing the DialogResult in the OK button handler? And if you're only ever adding one canvas, why not just use the canvas reference directly?

Comment: the 'ok' is not a `Button` type, i created a label and named it "ok", so i need the `MouseUp` because lables dont have `Click` event.
and i dont create only one canvas, the New_Paint window is being called several times.

Comment: You don't really "call" a window. I think that is where you are confused. What particular methods on the window are you calling?

Comment: if its not a call, then what is it?
i use the `ShowDialog` method and new window pops up, then when i click the 'ok' the `ok_MouseUp` methos is being called(among other methos)

Comment: Do you make a new instance of the window for each call to ShowDialog?

Comment: Yes thats what i do:

`private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`
        `{`
            `if (e.Key == Key.N)`
            `{`
                `Window NewDialog = new New_Paint();`
                `NewDialog.ShowDialog();`
            `}`
        `}`

Comment: It should look something like this: void WindowKeyDown(s,e) { if (e.Key == Key.N) { var nd = new New_Paint(); if(nd.ShowDialog() == true) list.Add(nd.Canvas); ...

Comment: but the canvas is being created in the other window, not the main window, the `KeyDown` event is in the main window

Comment: "but the canvas is being created in the other window" -- that's exactly what I'm saying about your list! C# uses a reference system to keep track of (heap) objects. As long as someone has a valid reference to a Canvas, it won't go away.